# What are these queries used for?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm using `sqlx` for the first times these days.

I just found out those queries executed from `sqlx` in my app, but I don't know what they are used for.

Can you help me understand?

```sql
SELECT
  typname,
  typtype,
  typcategory,
  typrelid,
  typelem,
  typbasetype
FROM
  pg_catalog.pg_type
WHERE
  oid = $1
```

and

```sql
SELECT
  attname,
  atttypid
FROM
  pg_catalog.pg_attribute
WHERE
  attrelid = $1
  AND NOT attisdropped
  AND attnum > 0
ORDER BY
  attnum
```

Comment: I'm guessing that's sqlx discovering the schemas of your database

Comment: Yeah, but it appears many times for the same query. And second, why does sqlx need to discover the db schema?

Comment: @FredHors Because sqlx typechecks your queries made with query! macro against it.

Comment: I’m not using macro, only query_as everywhere.